# MySQL won't connect to remote server. Always reverts to IP of local server

Tags: mysql

**Server 1** - 11.22.33.44

**Server 2** - 99.88.77.66

I'm trying to connect MySQL from server 1 to server 2, but when I do so it seems to revert the connection IP to its own server, where the user details are obviously incorrect so it fails.

```
Connected to Server 1 (11.22.33.44)

$ mysql -u root -p -h 99.88.77.66
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'11.22.33.44' (using password: YES)
```

It's like it doesn't try to connect to 99.88.77.66. On both servers there is a firewall rule allowing connection to both servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the target host used to authenticate.

"Access denied fo user xxx@target-host".

It's not about the connection, but what server(-name) you connect to, to authenticate. This technique adds another layer of security by seperating users within different networks.

`%` is used as a wildcard an means "any target host". See the mysql/users table.

The following is not the server for example:

```
root@localhost
root@127.0.0.1
root@%
```

You need `root@11.22.33.44` or `root@%` (not recommended!) in your mysql/users table to be able to connect.

Comment: I needed to add root@11.22.33.44 on the 99.88.77.66 server.

Comment: Right, that was a mistake by me.

Answer (score 0):

connect to mysql, use mysql database by this command

```
use mysql;
```

Check the users

```
select * from user;
```

and see if user `root` has the permission to access from `%`

Yon create a separate user for app by these commands:

```
create user user_name@'%' identified by 'password'
```

Grant all permissions to that user on your database tables

```
  grant all on database.* to 'user_name'@'%'
```

Don't forget to flush privileges

```
 flush privileges
```